# azure pipeline variable created in powershell script not displaying value

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In an Azure Pipeline, I want to set a variable in a Powershell script and then use that variable in a later build step. The variable doesn't print out a value.

In my Powrshell script I hardcode a value for testing purposes:

```
$packageFolder = 'dotnet/TestPackage/'
##vso[task.setvariable variable=changedPackage;isOutput=true]$packageFolder
```

Here is my YAML file:

```
steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: 'Detect Subfolder Changes'
    name: setvarStep
    inputs:
      targetType: 'filePath'
      filePath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\detectchanges.ps1
      failOnStderr: true
 - script: echo "$(setvarStep.changedPackage)"
 - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2 
   displayName: 'dotnet build'
   condition: ne('$(setvarStep.changedPackage)', '')
   inputs: 
      projects: '$(setvarStep.changedPackage)'
```

When the pipeline gets to the script step it just prints out this:

```
Script contents:
echo "$(setvarStep.changedPackage)"
```

I don't think the variable is actually set. When the pipeline gets to the dotnet build step it throws an error: `##[error]Project file(s) matching the specified pattern were not found`.

While having debugging turned on I noticed this in the dotnet build step logs: `##[debug]findPath: 'C:\agents\librarywin-1\_work\2\s\$(setvarStep.changedPackage)'`

I think my issue is the pipeline variable syntax is wrong even though I'm following the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-a-multi-job-output-variable) on Microsoft's website. I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need double quote the logging command:

detectchanges.ps1:

```
$packageFolder = 'dotnet/TestPackage/'
"##vso[task.setvariable variable=changedPackage;isOutput=true]$packageFolder"
```

YAML:

```
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Detect Subfolder Changes'
  name: setvarStep
  inputs:
    targetType: 'filePath'
    filePath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\detectchanges.ps1
    failOnStderr: true
- script: echo "$(setvarStep.changedPackage)"
```

Comment: Thanks. Adding the parentheses did the trick. I knew it had to be something minor.

Answer (score 1):

You should have `Write-Host`

```
$packageFolder = 'dotnet/TestPackage/'
Write-Host ##vso[task.setvariable variable=changedPackage;isOutput=true]$packageFolder
```

like here

[image]